# Adding a connection the Virtual Network Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, ipsec

I am trying to create a Site-to-Site (IPsec) connection of Virtual Network gateway in Azure through the portal, and getting an error `Failed to create connection 'TestIpSec'. Error: A retryable error occurred.`

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Appreciate, if anyone comes up with a resolution, please. Thanks

Moreover, the status of the virtual network gateway is updating... not sure why?

[Update Status on Network Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNuIn.png)

Comment: The issue is resolved. The network gateway status was "Updating" I reset the gateway and I am able to create the connection

Comment: If the issue is resolved, you could post your solution and accept it, refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks, @NancyXiong - I don't see any option to accept the answer

Comment: It must wait for 48 hours on your own answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

The issue is resolved. The network gateway status was "Updating" I reset the gateway and I am able to create the connection

Answer (score 0):

If deleting the connection and resetting the gateway does not fix the issue, you may need to delete and re-create the local network gateway as well. I had to resort to that after multiple attempts to re-create a connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Network Gateways appear in your resources before they're fully deployed. If you try to make changes to the gateway or configure a connection before the deployment is completed you'll also get this error.